# One alphabet in a different font

Tags: fonts, sans-serif

I wanted a sans serif font in Latex, where the capital I looks different than the small l. I came across droid font, which is nice but too wide and takes up too much space. Currently, I am using

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

The "solution" I am thinking of is to only use capital I of the droid font, with everything else remaining the same. Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: Please, do not do this. Glyphs from different font are generally incompatible: they have different stroke thickness, different tip roundness, etc. I'm tempted to say that it's even better to design a new letter into the font. And btw, the two letters are distingueshed quite well in CMSS: the `I` is reasonably thicker than the `l`.

Comment: not that it helps, but there's an amusing tugboat article by chuck bigelow, ["oh, oh, zero"](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-2/tb107bigelow-zero.pdf), about the confusing nature of "ohs" and zeros, and ones, "ells", and "eyes".  the problem has been around for a long time.

Comment: Take a look at the `cabin` font. Not only is small l different from capital I, but it has smallcaps in all shapes/weights (including semibold)  and also exists in Opentype format.

Comment: @tohecz Any explanation on how to "design a new letter into the font"? I am not familiar with that idea at all

Comment: @Ankush I don't know how to design a new letter nor how to make LaTeX use it. I'm sure that this all this is solvable by LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED, not only because of tohecz's comment, but because making letters active can break all sorts of things (e.g., any macro with a capital "I" in its name).  Nonetheless, here is a way to use a different capital I without creating a whole new font.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\let\svcapi I
\catcode`I=\active
\defI{$\mathcal{\svcapi}$}
\begin{document}
Is this doing capital I in a different font?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, to achieve a manual implementation that avoids the active letter problem, you could `\def\myI{$\mathcal{\svcapi}$}` and use `\myI{}` whereever you wanted the alternate "I", as in `\myI{}s this doing capital \myI{} in a different font?`

Comment: Yep, this breaks usage of any macros where `I` is in the title. The error Undefined control sequence knows to be very confusing in these situations, and that's the better things that can happen.

Comment: This makes the I a mathcal symbol. How do I make it droid font I?

Comment: @Ankush  I am not familiar with the droid font, to know the answer, but I'll see what I can find.

Comment: @Ankush I am sorry, but I am unable to get the droid font working on my system (though I found it on CTAN).  So I can't play with it to answer your droid-specific question.  However, I'm thinking it might be something along the lines of `\def\myI{\fdsfamily I}`

Comment: \usepackage{droidsans} and then \def\myI{{\fdsfamily I}} works. But as you said it is not a pretty fix, works nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment, you can trys the `cabin` font. It also has small caps, greek and cyrillic glyphs. Here is a demo. As the kerning is rather tight, in my opinion, I used some letterspacing with the help of the `microtype` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\SetTracking[no ligatures = {f}]{encoding = *}{10}\lsstyle
In this font, the small letter \textcolor{Tomato3}{l} is noticeably different from capital \textcolor{Tomato3}{I} and from the number \textcolor{Tomato3}{1}: Prosper Mérimée wrote his fantastic novella ‘La Vénus d’Ille’ in 1835.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, it does not work on my system. I downloaded 4 different style files, but at the end it gives a serif font.